# How do I paste these values instead of formula using vba

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

pasting the values instead of formula using vba

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A6318,'https://-/-/-/-/-/-/-/[-.xlsx]-'!$A:$BO,2,FALSE),"")
```

I want to paste the answer on the cell A! without pasting the formula using VBA.

Comment: with paste.special values... but with or without vba - as I am confused by what you want.

Comment: using vba. do the formula but paste the value all in one cell and all in vba

Answer (score 3):

Note that I'm not sure if you can use a `https://` link as reference for a file in a formula at all. But here are 3 solutions:

1. You could use the [Application.Evaluate method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.evaluate) to get the result of a formula in VBA:

   ```
   Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = Evaluate("=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A6318,'https://-/-/-/-/-/-/-/[-.xlsx]-'!$A:$BO,2,FALSE),"""")")
   ```

---

2. Alternatively use the [WorksheetFunction.VLookup method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.vlookup) to do the lookup in VBA directly.

   ```
   Dim LookupResult As Variant
   On Error Resume Next 'next line throws error if no lookup result is found
   LookupResult = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Mysheet").Range("$A6318"), Workbooks("whatever.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheetname").Range("$A:$BO"),2,False)
   On Error Goto 0 're-activate error handling
   Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = LookupResult
   ```

   *Note that here `whatever.xlsx` needs to be already opened in Excel otherwise it won't work. So you probably need to download it temorarily and open it in Excel before.*

---

3. You could paste the formula and calculate. Then copy the formula result and paste it as values.

   ```
   Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A6318,'https://-/-/-/-/-/-/-/[-.xlsx]-'!$A:$BO,2,FALSE),"""")"
   Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value
   ```

Comment: Dim a As Worksheet
Set a = Worksheets("Sheet1")
a.range("e2").formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A6318,'https://-/-/-/-/-/-/-/[-.xlsx]-'!$A:$BO,2,FALSE),"""")"
a.range("e2").Value = a.range("e2").Value


Don't know why but this code doesn't work. Kept giving me run time error '1004' application-define or object-define error @PEH

Comment: @LimYiLong That means your formula is not correct. Test if your formula works if you put it into a cell manually and try to fix it.